# Postgresql 9.3 Fails on starting on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, postgresql

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 system, continuously running some automation work for me for a year already. The Postgresql 9.3 on board stop running since last week: it fails when starting and error message suggest me to check the log. However, there is nothing in the log.

Output for checking the status using `sudo service postgresql status`:

```
9.3/main (port 5432): down
```

Output for restarting PostgreSQL using `sudo service postgresql restart`:

```
* Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server
* The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output.
                                                                        [fail]
```

I have not updated anything or change any setting recently on that machine.

Any explanation or solution on this?

Comment: It's better to paste text than image. Post output of `sudo systemctl status postgresql`

Comment: @Redbob Looks like systemctl is not supported by 14.04. Any other suggestion?

Comment: `sudo service postgresql status`

Comment: @Redbob It shows 'down', updated above. Any chance the lower level dependencies of PostgreSQL update themselves automatically and thus crash this old version of PostgreSQL?

Comment: Postgresql is so simple to install. I don't think if its a dependency matter. You will need to review your `postgresql.conf` config file. is not your /var folder filled up?

Comment: @Redbob Totally make sense! Just found out I have no disk space on the device. That is also the reason no log is created. Thanks! Please leave this as an answer and I will accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, when postgresql suddenly stops, may be a signal that the space reserved for it was filled up. All postgresql stuff is stored into `/var`folder, mainly its database. So some good-practices should be adopted, **except to save space in /var**, because it may affect any other programs.

a) if you plan to reinstall your server and postgresql is critically essential, reserve a wider partition to `/var`folder, apart from root partition;

b) if your server is already running as also postgresql, you could migrate its database location to another partition. I found this article from Digital Ocean, it's very useful:

[How To Move a PostgreSQL Data Directory to a New Location on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-postgresql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04)

it works for 14.04 too, just change `systemctl` to `service` way.